# Write every value inside a char list

Tags: c#, foreach

I am trying to create a list of previous guesses in my hangman session:
It works but as my game asks for another guess until either lives == 0 or won = true this causes the foreach loop to make a new line for every previous guess like this:

Guessed Character: K

Guessed Character: B

round 3

Guessed Character: K

Guessed Character: B

Guessed Character: P

I want to be able to print like this:

Guessed Characters: K B P

```
List<char> lista_f_gissning = new List<char>();    
foreach(var item in lista_f_gissning)
{
    string s = item.ToString();
    Console.Write("Gissade Bokstäver:"+ s + '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the label out of the loop and remove the "\n":

```
Console.Write("Gissade Bokstäver:");

foreach(var item in lista_f_gissning)
{
   string s = item.ToString();
   Console.Write("{0} ", s);
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it.. +1 :)

Comment: You don't need the `item.ToString()`. You can use `item` itself. :)

Comment: @Tamim Salem
What if I have the following lists
lista_f_gissning (wrong guesses)
lista_r_gissning (correct guesses)
and want the foreach function to include both lists?

Comment: @Xiddic Do you want to iterate both lists together? Or you want separately?

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira
I tried this:
foreach(var item in lista_f_gissning.Concat(lista_r_gissning))

Also added using System.Linq; to the top.
Is it a solid solution?.

Comment: Should be fine, but you wont be able to distinguish between a right and wrong guess (character). and you'll print out everything.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the static `Join` function on string:

```
Console.WriteLine("Gissade Bokstäver: " + String.Join(" ", lista_f_gissning));
```

Comment: I think it's missing a `)` after `lista_f_gissning`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the a `Console.WriteLine` method to avoid `\n` concat, for sample:

```
Console.Write("Gissade Bokstäver: ");
foreach(var item in lista_f_gissning)      
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```